# Seeming hard-limit on image resolution?

Tags: image-processing, physics

I am trying to generate some very large images of the basins of attraction of a dynamical system. However, the resolution of the images seems to cap out at 10001 x 10001 pixels, and no arrangement of ImageResolution or ImageSize seems to fix this. As far as I can tell, Mathematica is encountering no errors as it runs this, and is able to accurately spit out a result, but for whatever reason, the image simply cannot exceed 10001 x 10001 pixels. I have combed the documentation and have not found any clues about any software or hardware limitations which may be present here. Any ideas?

Here's the code I'm using; on my machine, it spits out a 10001 x 10001 image, despite the resolution being set at 50000 x 50000:

```
(*2 magnets*)
n = 50000; (*number of pixels on each side of the image*)
{tmax, dt} = {25, 
  0.05}; (*Number of time steps and length of each time step*)
{k, c, h} = {0.1, 0.2, 
  0.1}; (*Damping coeffecient, Gravitational force coefficient, \
resting distance from surface*)
{z1, z2} = 
 2 N@Exp[I 2 Pi {1, 2}/
      2]; (*Locations in the complex plane of the magnets. Magnets \
can't be at the origin*)
l = 5.0;

z = Developer`ToPackedArray@
   Table[x + I y, {y, -l, l, 2 l/n}, {x, -l, l, 2 l/n}];
v = a = aold = 0 z;
Do[z += v dt + (4 a - aold) dt^2/6;
  vpredict = v + (3 a - aold) dt/2;
  anew = (z1 - z)/(h^2 + Abs[z1 - z]^2)^1.5 + (z2 - 
       z)/(h^2 + Abs[z2 - z]^2)^1.5 - c z - k vpredict;
  v += (5 anew + 8 a - aold) dt/12;
  aold = a; a = anew, {t, 0, tmax, dt}];
res = Abs[{z - z1, z - z2}];
Image[.7/res, Interleaving -> False, ColorSpace -> "GrayScale", ImageSize -> Full]
```

Comment: I'm guessing your complaint is on the display size? If so, you can make Mathematica _display_ images at true size with `ImageSize -> Magnification[1]`

Comment: When I export the image (by right-clicking and saying export as) it still gives a 10k x 10k image. I am attempting the simulation again with your fix implemented, but it will take some time, as it is a beefy program to run.

Comment: I'd just generate a random image. I had to optimize and compile parts of your code to get it to work within my patience limit. How are you exporting it? I have no issues getting `Export` to write a 100005x100005 pixel image.

Comment: I am exporting it by generating the image, then right-clicking and telling Mathematica to save as a PDF.

Comment: why a PDF? If you care about the image size I'd save as a PNG. I'm not sure what PDF does with such large images...Also my guess is there's something weird in the interface. I'd use `Export["wherever/you/want/it.png", %]` or something of that nature.

Comment: Admittedly, the PDF thing is a workaround from years ago when I appropriated this code from another author. I had issues with Mathematica crashing when I tried to export large images. I am attempting to export a 15k x 15k RandomImage now to see if the issue persists. EDIT: Mathematica crashed on exporting a 15k x 15k image as png. Had success with doing it as a PDF though. Going to attempt it with my code now.